# Hash variable to array (TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer)

Tags: ruby, arrays

noob here in ruby. I have this array of database connection

```
@db_connection = [:host => "localhost", 
        :port => 3306, 
        :username => "user", 
        :password => "password"]
```

but when i use it like

```
connection(@db_connection)
```

returns me this error

```
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

the array is working when placed statically in the connection() but when put it as a variable, it gives an error.

---

Edit:
I placed it inside `connection` method as

```
connection(:host => "localhost", 
           :port => 3306, 
           :username => "user", 
           :password => "password")
```

and placed it in a variable like my example above. BTW, Im new to ruby, and its a problem of hash vs. array like answer below. i apologize for the confusion to my question :)

Comment: Use `{..}` instead of `[...]` if you mean hash literal.

Comment: Can you share your failing and succeeding code? BTW, you've shown an array literal (consisting on one hash containing four key/value pairs), not a hash variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your hash with `{}`... as a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html)

```
@db_connection = {:host => "localhost"
                  :port => 3306, 
                  :username => "user", 
                  :password => "password"}
```

Or use the new Ruby `>= 1.9` style

```
@db_connection = {host: "localhost"
                  port: 3306, 
                  username: "user", 
                  password: "password"}
```

---

The problem is with your code here

```
@db_connection = [:host => "localhost", 
                  :port => 3306, 
                  :username => "user", 
                  :password => "password"]
```

Which evaluates to a hash wrapped in an array.

```
[{:host=>"localhost", :port=>3306, :username=>"user", :password=>"password"}]
```

It's valid Ruby code, but as soon as your `connection` method gets it, it's probably struggling to work with it.

---

**Edit:** using a stripped down example, here's what I'm guessing is happening.

```
def connection options
  puts "host is #{options[:host]}"
end

connection [host: "localhost"]

# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

What's happening here is you're trying to access a `Symbol` index (`:host`) on an Array. However, because arrays' are numerically indexed, the Array is trying to convert the symbol to an integer and it can't. Thus the `TypeError`.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the OP would get a different result if he passed that array literal to `connection` instead of the instance variable.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, it actually does. Arrays have completely different methods available to them compared to Hashes. If his `connection` function treats the array as a hash, he could run into trouble. I'll leave a more detailed explanation as an edit.

Comment: @maček I think you misunderstood my question. The OP said the array worked when placed statically in the connection. I interpreted that to mean that `connection([:host => "localhost", 
        :port => 3306, 
        :username => "user", 
        :password => "password"])` worked. That's what I didn't understand.

Comment: I interpreted that to mean `connection(:host => "localhost", ...)`. No problem. Cheers.